# Responsive text size inside div

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with some CSS.

I'm making some price-labels using PHP, but unfortunately when the product name is over three lines it will push the price-tag out of the div. Is it any way to make the size of the text responsive which constraints inside the Div?

> [image]

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle please? We can't do much without it...

Comment: Well, that won't work. I'm using PHP to output lines in an Excel-file. Maybe it helps to inspect the code: http://gamsmania.com/prislapper/auto/kinpluss2.php

Comment: It's not possible I'm afraid. You can check for the number of characters in each "tile" and reduce the font-size when you've reach a certain number...

Comment: @HenningHøgmoenHaugen Can't you just use the HTML output and create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems to have the price in the same content-block as the title of the product. I would separate the two so that the product name floats at the top while the price floats at the bottom; each in its own `div`. The only way you can implement client-side checks for element rendering is with JavaScript so I'd include a small snippet somewhere in your HTML (that is, if you prefer to not have JS..?).

By doing that, you can check the height of the title `div` with:

```
function countLines(Titlediv) {
    var Lines = (Titlediv.offsetHeight)/(Titlediv.style.lineHeight);
    alert(Lines);
}
```

If you want to force the title fit in 2 lines or less, then you need to evaluate a smaller font-size ratio depending on the `width` of the container div. I would check this JS API out: http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/